# How to know if record is last

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

So I have this query in SQL. I do I know if the record is the last in the recordset:

```
sql = SELECT * FROM table WHERE RID = 27
Set rs=Conn.Execute(sql)

If not rs.EOF Then

   iID = rs("RID")
   If iID = LAST Then response.write ("this is last record") End If

End If
Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you would need to do this but you could do something like this:

```
sql = SELECT * FROM table WHERE RID = 27
Set rs=Conn.Execute(sql)

If not rs.EOF Then

   rs.MoveNext
    If rs.EOF Then
       response.write ("this is last record") 
    End If

End If
Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
```

Given the nature of your query it looks like you would only get 1 row anyway so this seems kind of pointless.

Comment: I get what you're saying. This page is my detail page. So you're right, the query returns 1 row. Can I still use your example to know if this record is the last record in the table?

Comment: Sure, but like I said if there is only 1 row why bother with the extra code? You could use that same thing inside a loop though.

Comment: where do you insert the rs.MoveNext? After the Set rs-Conn.Execute(sql) line:

Comment: Perhaps you may need to check to see if there are *no* records by using `If rs.BOF and rs.EOF Then...`.

Comment: @Brasciole `rs.movenext` comes somewhere after `do while not rs.eof` the code you want to repeat for each record goes between.

Comment: @Brasciole I edited the code so you can see where you could do this. I would think you would want a loop here but it isn't totally clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
sql = "SELECT MAX(RID) FROM table "
Set rs=Conn.Execute(sql)

isLast = "no records"
If not rs.BOF Then
 if rs(0) = 27 then '' 27 or somone else for your taste 
    ifLast = "last record"
 else
    ifLast = "not last record"
 end if  
End If

Response.Write isLast

Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
%>
```